# How to trigger AWS lambda functions manually which is already scheduled using event bridge rules

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I am using event bridge to trigger a lambda function at 8 everyday to perform some ETL operations.
At times i receive requests to trigger the lambda manually ondemand. How can i achieve that using the same lambda function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to run the Lambda on demand like running it in the AWS Console, connecting it to an API Gateway and triggering it from the API Gateway etc.

But the easiest way is to use [Lambda URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-urls.html)

It will give you an URL that you can envoke that will run the Lambda.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/testing-functions.html

The laziest way would be to just run a "Test". They will still write to the log group in CloudWatch, and show up in the invocation list. You can save various tests (i.e., different JSON payloads).

I'm not 100% sure why they are labeled as "Tests" and not "Runs" in the console/GUI, and would be curious to know.

Comment: if your lambda notifies SNS async, it will not trigger on a "Test" - one important difference/feature or "Test" vs some other method of invocation